# Akka.Net ActorSelection Tells() not received to remote actor

Tags: akka.net

I am trying to initiate communication with a remote actor, if the remote system is up and running the code works fine, but if the remote system is not running when the first attempt to communicate is made all subsequent attempts fail too.

```
        var system = ActorSystem.Create("myClient");

        string line = null;
        while (line != "x")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying");
            var esb = system.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://myRemoteSystem@localhost:9391" + "/user/myActor");//.ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Result;
            esb.Tell(new MyMessage());

            line = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I have a simple console app which tries to talk to the remote system every time you press enter (as above) to show the scenario.

If the remote system is running before this client runs it connects fine.
If is not running for the first attempt, and the remote system is then started, the Tell will never reach the remote system. (Or at least not in the 10+ minutes I tried)

I have tried adjusting the Quarantine time down to 2 seconds and the Gating time. Neither of these seemed to have an affect.

I also tried Resolving the IActorRef with similar results, once it throws an ActorNotFound exception, it repeats this behavior even once the remote system is up and running.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to tell if the remote system is running before attempting to resolve the remote actor.